# Proper way to user requestAnimationFrame 'inside' requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe, slowdown

I'm using JavaScript with `requestAnimationFrame` to animation a Game.

However, I have a situation inside the main `requestAnimationFrame` that an 'IF' is done, and I would like to do an animation for X seconds if this 'IF' is true...

The ideia is do that second animation with another `requestAnimationFrame`, like the code above for reference:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
count = 0;
enteredHere = false;

var main = function(now){

setTimeout(function () {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
  var nowSeconds = Math.floor(now)/1000;
    count++;

  context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "#f00";
    context.font = "20px arial";
    //context.fillText(count, 10, 30);
    context.fillRect(10,30,count, 10);

  nowSeconds = parseInt(Math.floor(now)/1000);
    if(nowSeconds % 5 == 0){
     if(!enteredHere){
       enteredHere = true;
      doSomething();
      }
    }   
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
  }, 1000 / 60);  
};

var doSomething = function(){    
  context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "#f00";
    context.font = "20px calibri";
    context.fillText('DoSomething', 10, 70);
 
    requestAnimation = requestAnimationFrame(doSomething);

  setTimeout(function(){
     cancelAnimationFrame(requestAnimation);
      enteredHere = false;
    },2000);
};

main();
```

```html
<canvas width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

As you can see, when the second animation is happening, the first one(the `fillRect` growing) slow down and when it finishes (2 seconds) the first come back to normal.

Can someone explain why the first `requestAnimationFrame` slow down when the second happens?

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post your working code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just include your code, right here in your question as a "code snippet".

Comment: Thanks! First post, sorry!